# Solr Admin UI not accessible (You do not have permission to view the security panel)

Tags: json, solr, admin

I just settled up a Solr server (no cloud mode). It is running and I already created 3 cores and loaded some data in them. The problem is that I cannot access the admin security panel, which retrieves me the error "You do not have permission to view the security panel.".
I already modified the "security.json" file in the folder var/solr/data/ in the following way but it is still not working:

```
{
   "authentication":{
      "blockUnknown":false,
      "class":"solr.BasicAuthPlugin",
      "credentials":{
         "solr":"encrypted password"
      },
      "realm":"My Solr users",
      "forwardCredentials":false,
      "":{
         "v":0
      }
   },
   "authorization":{
      "class":"solr.RuleBasedAuthorizationPlugin",
      "permissions":[
         {
            "name":"security-edit",
            "role":"admin"
         },
         {
            "name":"security-read",
            "role":"admin"
         },
         {
            "name":"all",
            "role":"admin"
         }
      ],
      "user-role":{
         "solr":"admin"
      }
   }
}
```

How can I solve this?
Thank you for the help